# ulimit on a Specific Directory

Tags: ulimit

I know about [ulimit](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/61334), which is used to set the size of the maximum file size, but this setting is global on the server. Is there a way to set a limit to the file size per directory? For example, I want the maximum file size under /dir1 to be 1 MB and under /dir2 to be 2 MB.

Note: I want my settings to be independent of users/groups.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, either with `ulimit` or otherwise.  A file can have links in several directories.  If a file has links in `/dir1` and `/dir2` and the two directories have different limits you get conflicting restrictions.  For this reason any kind of limiting mechanism can only act on inodes, not on paths.